# xslt - strange thing when place root tag out of the <xsl:template>

Tags: xslt-2.0

I get xml from url: http://www.concert.ru/mail-ru/concert.xml
And I need tags ActionPlaces and Actions to be handled in separate manner - so I use two different  tags for  them:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="Data/ActionPlaces"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Data/Actions"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But they should be enveloped inside tag called enfinity
So when I do like this:

```
<enfinity>
     <xsl:template match="Data/Actions">..
     <xsl:template match="Data/ActionPlaces"> ..
</enfinity>
```

I get incorrect output. When the main tag is inside one of templates - I get correct output - but need main tag to be the top. How to handle it?

Comment: Please show the input XML, the expected output XML and the actual output.  Without that we cannot tell what is happening.

Comment: It is very huge - I gave link to input xml.

Comment: Then reduce it to a minimal example, and show INPUT, EXPECTED OUTPUT, and INCORRECT OUTPUT.

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `<enfinity><xsl:apply-templates select="Data/Actions"/><xsl:apply-templates select="Data/ActionPlaces"/></enfinity>`?

Comment: @EeroHelenius has answered the question.  (But has done so in a comment, instead of an answer.  If you move your answer to an answer, the OP can accept it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <enfinity>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Data/ActionPlaces"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Data/Actions"/>
  </enfinity>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: YA, cool it works - but why does it adds xmlns="" now each category tag - is it a serious issue?

Comment: @user1573964 No, that's not serious. It only means that those elements do not belong to any namespace. That said, it's not beautiful to look at. Why don't you research how to remove it? Or else, ask it in a new question - and post a full XSLT stylesheet.